How to make `Alt + Shift + 0` work (to change the input language) on Windows 10?
I assigned Alt+Shift+0 to en-US but nothing happened when I pressed. And this shortcut just disappeared randomly after reboot.
Alt+Shift+9 and Alt+Shift+8 assigned for zh-CN and Japanese are both working correctly.

Perhaps some process already uses this combination as hotkey. Try to check this using solution described here: How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?
